# How to post Production journal table from code?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, journal

I create from code the record in two *tables* `ProdJournalTable` (header) and `ProdJournalProd` (lines).

I inserted all records in both tables well, without problems.

After that I want to to *post* this *Journal*.

I used this code:

```
ProdJournalCheckPostProd::newPostJournal(myProdJournalProd.JournalId, true);
```

I execute the method, but in fact not register the journal, in Form *Production journal* my record have yet to be registered. I call the class under the button in the *Form*, certainly not good. If I clicked on button I post the journal without problem.

The Journal and the form is in :

**Production control -> Journals -> Report as Finished**

I'm writing this Journal *Report as Finished*.

How do you post from code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `newPostJournal` methods returns a `ProdJournalCheckPostProd` object. It does *not* post the journal.

If you *really* want to post the journal, call the `run` method.

```
ProdJournalCheckPostProd::newPostJournal(myProdJournalProd.JournalId, true).run();
```